# How to convert the following Quadratic optimization problem to a linear one?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, binary-programming

I have an optimization problem

$$Min : \ 3x_{11} + 5x_{12} + 4x_{21} + 3 x_{22}  - (10x_{11}x_{22} + 2x_{12}x_{21})$$
subject to the following constraints :

$$ x_{11} + x_{12} = 1$$
$$ x_{21} + x_{22} = 1$$

where $x_{11}. x_{12}, x_{21}, x_{22}$ are Integer Variables taking values either $0$ or $1$.

How do I convert the objective function to a linear one?

Comment: See https://or.stackexchange.com/q/37/38

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $x_{11}x_{22}= 1$ if and only if $x_{11}=x_{22}=1$. Define new binary variables $z_1$, $z_2$, replace $x_{11}x_{22}$ with $z_1$, replace $x_{12}x_{21}$ with $z_2$, and add the following constraints:

\begin{align}
z_1 &\leqslant x_{11}\tag1\\
z_1 &\leqslant x_{22}\tag2\\
z_1 &\geqslant x_{11}+x_{22}-1\tag3\\
z_2 &\leqslant x_{12}\tag4\\
z_2 &\leqslant x_{21}\tag5\\
z_2 &\geqslant x_{12}+x_{21}-1\tag6.
\end{align}
Constraints $(1)$ and $(2)$ ensures that $z_1$ can only take value $1$ when $x_{11}=x_{22}=1$. Constraint $(3)$ ensures that $z_1$ actually does take values $1$ when $x_{11}=x_{22}=1$. Constraints $(4)$, $(5)$, and $(6)$ play a similar role for $z_2$. Our resulting binary integer program is
\begin{align}
\min&\quad 3x_{11}+5x_{12} + 4x_{21} + 3x_{22} -10z_1 -2z_2\\
\mathrm{s.t.}&\quad x_{11}+x_{12} = 1\\
&\quad x_{21} + x_{22} =1\\
&\quad z_1 \leqslant x_{11}\\
&\quad z_1 \leqslant x_{22}\\
&\quad z_1 \geqslant x_{11}+x_{22}-1\\
&\quad z_2 \leqslant x_{12}\\
&\quad z_2 \leqslant x_{21}\\
&\quad z_2 \geqslant x_{12}+x_{21}-1\\
&\quad x_{11},x_{12},x_{21},x_{22},z_1,z_2\in\{0,1\}.
\end{align}
Adding slack variables to convert this into the standard form $\{\min c^Tx : Ax=b, x\geqslant 0\}$, we have
\begin{align}
\min&\quad 3x_{11}+5x_{12} + 4x_{21} + 3x_{22} -10z_1 -2z_2\\
\mathrm{s.t.}&\quad x_{11}+x_{12} = 1\\
&\quad x_{21} + x_{22} =1\\
&\quad -x_{11}+z_1  + s_1 = 0\\
&\quad - x_{22} +z_1  + s_2 =0\\
&\quad x_{11}+x_{22}-z_1 + s_3 = 1\\
&\quad - x_{12} +z_2 + s_4  = 0\\
&\quad - x_{21}+z_2 + s_5  = 0\\
&\quad x_{12}+x_{21} - z_2 + s_6 = 1\\
&\quad x_{11},x_{12},x_{21},x_{22},z_1,z_2\in\{0,1\}.
\end{align}
We have
$$
c = \begin{pmatrix}3&5&4&3&-10&-2&0&0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}^T,
$$
$$
b = \begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&1&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}^T,
$$
and 
$$
A = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
It turns out that $A$ is totally unimodular (as verified by the $\texttt{is_totally_unimodular}$ function in the $\texttt{lintools}$ package of $\texttt R$. Since $b$ is integral, every vertex of the polytope $\{Ax=b,x\geqslant 0\}$ is integral, so we may solve this integer program by general linear programming methods. Indeed an optimal basis is $(x_{11},1_{22},z_1,s_6) = (1,1,1,1)$  with objective value $-4$.

Comment: You have an error in the first sentence.

Comment: @RobPratt Thanks, I have corrected it.

Comment: You must have another error somewhere because the optimal objective value is $-4<8$.

Comment: @RobPratt Turns out I was using $\max$ for the objective function instead of $\min$. Thanks for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 1):

The general linearization of a product of binary variables is overkill here.  Instead, first substitute $x_{12} = 1 - x_{11}$ and $x_{22} = 1 - x_{21}$ to obtain objective function
\begin{align}
&3x_{11} + 5x_{12} + 4x_{21} + 3 x_{22}  - 10x_{11}x_{22} - 2x_{12}x_{21}\\
&=3x_{11} + 5(1 - x_{11}) + 4x_{21} + 3 (1 - x_{21})  - 10x_{11}(1 - x_{21}) - 2(1 - x_{11})x_{21}\\
&=3x_{11} + 5 - 5 x_{11} + 4x_{21} + 3 - 3 x_{21}  - 10x_{11} +10x_{11} x_{21} - 2x_{21} +2 x_{11} x_{21}\\
&=8 - 12x_{11} - x_{21} +12x_{11} x_{21}.
\end{align}
Now introduce $y \ge 0$ to represent $x_{11} x_{21}$.  Because we are minimizing, and the objective coefficient is $12>0$, we need only enforce $y\ge x_{11} x_{21}$, which we can do with a single linear constraint $y\ge x_{11} + x_{21} - 1$.  In summary, the problem is to minimize $$8 - 12x_{11} - x_{21} +12y$$ subject to:
\begin{align}
y&\ge x_{11} + x_{21} - 1\\
x_{11} &\in \{0,1\}\\
x_{12} &\in \{0,1\}\\
y &\ge 0
\end{align}
The optimal solution is $(x_{11},x_{21},y)=(1,0,0)$, which yields objective value $-4$ and corresponds to $(x_{11},x_{12},x_{21},x_{22})=(1,0,0,1)$ in the original space.